# UIPickerView Set Selected Row by Title

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I'm trying to select a row from code of a UIPickerView that holds a list of locations.  The pickerview's content is loaded at runtime from a server, and I have the location the user used  when they logged in last.

I know I can use `[pickerview selectrow:int ...]` to select a row by the number, but I need to match the previous location to the location in the picker to get the row number.  I haven't been able to find method that helps me do that.

If I have been unclear, I am essentially trying to find the row number of an element in a `UIPickerView` via the title of the row.

Thanks!

Comment: presumably, you have access to the back-end data source used to populate the pickerview, you should do your search on that to get the proper index for `selectRow`

Comment: That makes more sense.  The source is the values in a dictionary.  I'll see if I can get the location of 'the location' from the dictionary

Comment: Just do the opposite of what you do in `titleForRow`

Answer (score 3):

If your picker only shows `NSStrings` you could do this.

```
NSUInteger index = [locationsArray indexOfObject:@"London"];
```