# UIPickerView select row where title == String in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uipickerview

I have a `UIPickerView` and I would like to select a row where title is equal to String , which I receive from my php/mysql script.

Let's say that this is my Array:

```
var myArray = ["First","Second","Third","Fourth","Sixth","Seventh"]
```

And this is what I get from my php script (That's what I want my `UIPickerView` to select.):

```
let myString = "Second"
```

So my question is:

How can I do something like this: `self.myPicker.selectRow(1, inComponent: 0, animated: true)` but I want myPicker to select row with title: "Second".

I have found this question but it is in objective-c : [UIPickerView Set Selected Row by Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976162/uipickerview-set-selected-row-by-title)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why -1 ?? :D What's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you doesn't know the index of your object in array than try like this.

```
let index = myArray.indexOf(myString)
self.myPicker.selectRow(index, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
```

If you are working with swift 3 then find index like this.

```
let index = myArray.index(of: myString)
```

**Edit:** If you doesn't sure that your array is contain your string than you can check for nil also.

```
if let index = myArray.indexOf(myString) {
    self.myPicker.selectRow(index, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Thank you thats exactly what I have been looking for :)

Comment: Welcome mate :) Happy coding :)